# Switching users from root in a Rundeck job (Cannot create session: Already running in a session)

Tags: linux, shell, devops, ubuntu-16.04, rundeck

I am trying to test a scheduled job on Rundeck by running specific commands on a 16.04 Ubuntu box, and one of those will be to switch the user from `root` to `nodeworker`.

the sequence is:

1. Accessing the right directory as root
   `cd /var/www/...` (Runs with no issues)
2. Switching to user `nodeworker`, no password needed
   `su nodeworker`
3. running the command `git pull origin master`

I tried running it with `sudo su - nodeworker -c "command here"`, same issue, that did not work either. I ended up tailing the `auth.log` to find that `su` is giving an error for starting a session when the root session is existing, and I have no idea of a fix for it:

`pam_systemd(su:session): Cannot create session: Already running in a session`

And I found this issue reported for Debian, https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=825949

Answer (score 0):

same here with rundeck user. it's used to work but not anymore. Workaround solution is creating the user (system type) manually before install the rundeck